# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'node:timers/promises' using middy 4 with node 16

Tags: node.js, timer, enoent, middy

Good afternoon, I have the following error every time I run the tests:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68fQD.png)

I'm migrating node14 to node 16 and i updated @middy/core from 3.2.2 to 4.2.2.

I checked the error in file index.cjs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRffc.png)

I have seen that appears two definitions.
Have you had a similar problem? please.

Comment: Can you remove node modules and install dependencies again?